# change function return value

Tags: windbg, sos

I have a .net application that is doing COM interop and calling some native library APIs. One of these APIs are returning some data that is unexpected and causing headaches for me. I am looking for some way of forcing the return value of the managed API. This is not going to solve my problem but help me narrow a few things down. I am simplifying things a bit below.

Keeping all this in mind, Let's say my managed class name MyClass and it has two methods ParentMethod() and ChildMethod(). ParentMethod calls ChildMethod which internally calls those native APIs. The ChildMethod itself returns a bool.

After breaking into my app via Windbg I first ran !dumpheap -type MyClass command that gave me following output

> 0:027> !dumpheap -type MyClass
>    Address       MT     Size
>   0ac7e7e4 04ac5030      100
>   total 0 objects
>   Statistics:
>         MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
>   04ac5030        1          100 MyNamespace.MyClass
>   Total 1 objects

I then ran following command trying to get the address of the methods in this class.

> 0:027> !dumpmt -md 04ac5030
>   EEClass:      04ac1b20
>   Module:       04ac49c8
>   Name:         MyNamespace.MyClass
>   mdToken:      02000002
>   File:         MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   BaseSize:        0x64
>   ComponentSize:   0x0
>   Slots in VTable: 61
>   Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 4
>   MethodDesc Table
>      Entry MethodDesc      JIT Name
>   04b20270   04ac4fd0      JIT MyNamespace.MyClass..ctor()
>   04b20230   04ac4ffc      JIT MyNamespace.MyClass..cctor()
>   04acc081   04ac4fd8     NONE MyNamespace.MyClass.ParentMethod()
>   04acc085   04ac4fe4     NONE MyNamespace.MyClass.ChildMethod()
>   04b202c0   04ac4ff0      JIT MyNamespace.MyClass.InitializeComponent()

I have found [Naveen's blog entry](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/03/14/piracy-in-net-silverlight-code-part-1-even-when-the-code-is-obfuscated/) where he describes some technique of doing something along the same line but I couldn't figure out what exact step should I take from here. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are simple steps

1. `bp 04acc085` - Which is the ChildMethod
2. When the break-point hits then issue the command `bp poi(@esp)` which sets the break-point on return register
3. And the when the second break-point hits you could change the value to true using `r eax=00000001` . The `eax` register stores the return value in x86

Or another way is to `bp 04acc085 "gu;r eax=00000001;gc"` which will do the same in one line

Comment: Thanks again Naveen. So just for my understanding what is the significance of @esp with the poi. My understanding is that poi is just like de-reference an address.

Comment: The @esp register stores the function return address. So by issuing bp poi(@esp) we are setting a break-point on the return address.